# Ubuntu 14.04 installation fail (dual boot with windows 7)

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, disk, sata

I was installing Ubuntu 14.04 when it said it failed and it would generate a log. After some seconds it opens a windows saying it is my disk problem and I should take care of the health of it.

When I tried for the second time it reconizes the previous ubuntu installation (strange, because before the second time I logged into windows).

Other strange think is the installation doesn't recognize windows in both tries (it only appears to install Ubuntu, erase the previous instalation and advanced option).

My disk have the following partitions:
1 ntfs (windows 7)
1 ntfs (for general data)
1 swap
1 ext 4

I tried Speedfan to run some S.M.A.R.T test, here are the results: http://www.hddstatus.com/hdrepshowreport.php?ReportCode=8166795&ReportVerification=BBE6CB99

Thanks for reading and a I appreaciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "BLOCKING ISSUE : your hard disk has 1485 pending sectors (this value is very large and our hard disk should be replaced)."
2. "BLOCKING ISSUE : your hard disk has 1485 offline uncorrectable sectors (this value is very large and your hard disk should be replaced)"
3. "NOTE : your hard disk Power On Hours Count attribute current value (93) is below the normal range (98 - 100) reported for your specific hard disk model. Basically your hard disk was powered on for more than the maximum time the average user did. "
4. "NOTE : your hard disk Power Cycle Count attribute current value (99) is below the normal range (100 - 100) reported for your specific hard disk model. Basically your hard disk was power cycled more times than the maximum number the average hard disk was. "

This is what I saw when I clicked the first link. It looks like your hard drive maybe old. Consider the age of the hard drive and if it matches what is described in the report then replace the hard drive.

In the second hard drive status tool report link.

"SERIOUS ISSUE : your hard disk has 1429 reallocated sectors. Hard disks do have spare sectors (usually from 256 up to 2560) used to replace bad ones. This remapping operation is transparent to the end user. Anyway, this can lead to degraded performances (because remapped sectors are in different places of the disk than the original ones and the head needs additional moving). If reallocated sectors grow over time, you might encounter some serious troubles. A backup of the most important data is suggested anyway."

It's looking like a hardware issue here unfortunately. Otherwise if you suspect that it may be a software issue backup and format the drive.